# Atualizar Imagem

Tags: android, android-activity

Estou com uma duvida, pois estou setando a imagem a partir da posição do Spinner.
Então, quando abre a activity, o metódo OnCreate le a posição do spinner e carrega a imagem de acordo com o seu tipo.

Porem, gostaria de saber como setar a posição do Spinner sempre que o usuário clica no spinner e troca de posição.

```
teste = arrayLitros.get(spnProdutos.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString();
    teste2 = arrayUnidadeL.get(spnProdutos.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString();


    if(teste.equals("20") && teste2.equals("L")){
        imgProduto.setImageResource(R.drawable.img1);
    }
    else if(teste.equals("10") && teste2.equals("L")){
        imgProduto.setImageResource(R.drawable.img2);
    }
    else if(teste.equals("2") && teste2.equals("L")){
        imgProduto.setImageResource(R.drawable.img3);
    }
    else if(teste.equals("3") && teste2.equals("M")){
        imgProduto.setImageResource(R.drawable.img4);
    }
```

Comment: Use um `OnItemSelectedListener.` e atribua-o ao *spinner* com `setOnItemSelectedListener()`

Comment: Valeu pela luz, não estava me atentando aos métodos existentes.